# Website integration: Frame, redirect or virtual domain?

Tags: mod-rewrite, hosting, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm overwhelmed by the many choices one has in website design. I'm probalbly asking something really easy to set up, but since I don't have any experience, I'm looking for help.

#### Current Setup

1. I've got a domain *mydomain.com* and ftp access to it. The apache webserver has mod_rewrite and perl installed (if that helps). I set up a subdomain *user.mydomain.com* that is currently pointing to the `http://www.mydomain.com/user` directory.
2. I've created a draft website running in the [*werc*](http://werc.cat-v.org/) framework on a different linux machine. This server has no domain name, I can access it using the static IP or `mywebsite.dyndns.org`. *werc* supports virtual hosting, but I don't quite understand it and know if it helps me here. I'm running lighttp (w/ `vhost` and `mod_rewrite`) and have full root permission, so anything is possible on this end.

#### Problem

I would like to run the *werc* site inside the subdomain *user.mydomain.com*. The URL in the browser should be *user.mydomain.com*, i.e. no apparent redirecting to the actual *werc* server IP should take place.

What's the best way to achieve that? I tried `mod_rewrite` on the *mydomain.com* machine, but I could only redirect. I think one could use a seperate "frame" for the werc hosted site, but that feels a little unclean. E.g. what would happen to the `<title>` tag?

What are my options? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I answered this here, instead, since it's purely a server configuration question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by adding a `CNAME` record for the sub domain `user.mydomain.com` with your DNS provider (or local name server, whichever you are using).

A `CNAME` says  "This `user.mydomain.com` is just an alias for `mywebsite.dyndns.org`.

Then, name your virtual host on the subdomain server `user.mydomain.com`, and you won't have to go through any kind of redirection or re-write rules for it to work.

I'm not sure where you host DNS for `mydomain.com`, but almost every provider out there lets you setup a `CNAME` record through the control panel. If you are locally hosting DNS (e.g. BIND on the Linux box), add this to the zone file for `mydomain.com` (e.g.):

```
user.mydomain.com.        CNAME  mysite.dyndns.org
```

More on CNAME records can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record).

Comment: OK, I just learnt that this provider doesn't allow `CNAME` records for other servers, only for directories on that server. sucks... I guess I have to live with redirect then? anyway, answer was very helpful -- accepted.

Comment: There are some excellent free DNS hosting providers that give you full access to your zone records. It would probably be worth it to investigate some for the future, as being able to add a quick work around (like this one) will really speed up your work. Some hosting compaies / registrars are just morons, unfortunately.